# why tseries package stop working on Jupyter notebook after it was running perfectly?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am downloading packages to R via Jupyter notebook using the following command

```
install.packages('tseries', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

this was working perfectly well until right now it just does not like to work.

i then coded `library(tseries)`

the result was

```
Error in library(tseries): there is no package called 'tseries'
Traceback:

1. library(tseries)
2. stop(txt, domain = NA)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I used `conda install -c r r-tseries=0.10_35` and worked!